# Need cm family only for bold italic Greeks

Tags: bold, italic, euler

In my document, I need to use `Palatino` as my text font and `Euler` for math font, I'm using the following code for this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino,mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}%
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\varphi}\quad \varphi$
\end{document}
```

But I need the `CM` font for `bold-italic` Greeks, i.e `\varphi` should be in Euler font and `\boldsymbol{\varphi}` is in standard `CM` family, please advise how to achieve it...

Any advise for my requirement? Please....

Note that I'm using `LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf`

Comment: Can you clarify why the bold Euler symbol needs to be replaced? There might be a better solution.

Comment: One of my professor wants to differentiate the bold symbol from the roman symbol....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend that.  Nevertheless, if your prof ordered you to, it’s probably not a battle worth fighting.  Here’s how.

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load Latin Modern or New Computer Modern with `range=\mbfvarphi` to redefine bold upright `\varphi`, `range=bfup/{Greek,greek}` to redefine all bold upright Greek, or `range=bfup` to redefine the bold upright alphabet.  You can use any math font, or any bold upright font that supports Greek.  This example requires you to download [the font Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf).

I warn you in advance that it’s likely that this is a lot more complicated than it needs to be and `\setmathfont{Neo Euler}` would work for you.  I do a lot of extra set-up to get `unicode-math` to use Neo Euler only for the symbols the font has, and fall back to a different math font for everything else (as well as digits and, of course, Greek).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\unimathsetup{math-style=upright, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={bfup/{latin, Latin}, frak, bffrak, cal},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={up/num, bfup/num, it, bfit, scr, bfscr,
                    sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit, tt}
            ]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{Greek,greek}]{NewCMMath-Book}

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\symbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ u, v, w, \varphi, \vartheta, \vectorsym{v}, \vectorsym{\varphi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler / New Computer Modern Math sample]

For comparison, using only the letters from Neo Euler, you would get:

[image: Neo Euler sample]

If you are also required to use PDFLaTeX, you can define a weird math alphabet that uses Euler in `\mathversion{normal}` and Computer Modern in `\mathversion{bold}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eucal, eufrak, eulervm}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{weirdletters}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{weirdletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol\Gamma    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Delta    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Theta    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Lambda   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Xi       {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Pi       {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Sigma    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Upsilon  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Phi      {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Psi      {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Omega    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda} {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi} {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"27}
\DeclareMathSymbol\upOmega  {\mathord}{weirdletters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol\upDelta  {\mathord}{weirdletters}{"01}

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ u, v, w, \varphi, \vartheta, \vectorsym{v}, \vectorsym{\varphi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler / Computer Modern sample]

I have to say, I disagree with your professor that this looks better.  If you’re at least allowed to substitute a different font, you could use one of the three or so upright legacy math fonts that contain Greek, for example, Math Design Charter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eucal, eufrak, eulervm}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{weirdletters}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{weirdletters}{bold}{OML}{mdbch}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol\Gamma    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Delta    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Theta    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Lambda   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Xi       {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Pi       {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Sigma    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Upsilon  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Phi      {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Psi      {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Omega    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}   {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda} {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}     {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}    {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}  {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi} {\mathalpha}{weirdletters}{"27}
\DeclareMathSymbol\upOmega  {\mathord}{weirdletters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol\upDelta  {\mathord}{weirdletters}{"01}

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ u, v, w, \varphi, \vartheta, \vectorsym{v}, \vectorsym{\varphi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler / Math Design Charter]

Comment: Much thanks, my professor satisfied with the second option as you provided for `PDFLaTeX` ....

Comment: The Professor asked me to convey his heartfull thanks to you ....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Tell him I was happy to help.